# UI Bootstrap - Angular datepicker ng-model format

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am using the datepicker from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="d MMMM yyyy" 
    ng-model="myDetails.makeNow.completedDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
    ng-required="true" close-text="{% trans %} task.close {% endtrans %}" 
    is-open="completedDate.opened" />
```

With this, the contents of the input box might say: `9 December 2015` due to the format I specified.

However `myDetails.makeNow.completedDate` will have: `2015-12-08T16:00:00.000Z`

What do I need to change so that `myDetails.makeNow.completedDate` will also contain `9 December 2015`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change, when you use on `{{myDetails.makeNow.completedDate | date : 'd MMMM yyyy'}}` its return `9 December 2015`.

If you enter a date of, say, 9 December 2015 into your date picker, that's midnight GMT. If you live west of England, say, in the U.S., it's 8 December 2015.

Comment: Thanks - but ideally I want to ignore any potential changes in timezone. I literally just want the string, as it appears in the textbox. `9 December 2015` is there anything I can do to ensure I always get that date, irrespective of timezone?

Comment: look on `bs3-angular-datepicker`, hope it will meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In the datepicker from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ if you display date ( i.e ng-model="dt"), date is displayed in `2015-12-08T16:00:00.000Z`format only. To display the date in format `d MMMM yyyy` you can use filter